# Counterexample for statement: $2$ is always a valid subobject classifier

Tags: category-theory, examples-counterexamples

In the category $\mathbf{Sets}$, the subobject classifier is $2$, i.e. a two-element set.
I understand that, but I don't understand why $\Omega$ is not $2$-like for some of the other categories.

By "$2$-like object" I mean such object $A$, so that there are exactly two different morphisms $1 \rightarrow A$.

Please walk me through a counterexample in the following format:

1. Pick a category $C$ that has a subobject classifier which is not $2$-like.
2. Forget about the original $\Omega$ and assume that the subobject classifier $2$-like.
3. Show that the definition of a subobject classifier does not hold (e.g. you can't form the pullback square).

I don't want to ask for a specific counterexample category, because I don't know in which category the counterexample will be the easiest to show. If $\mathbf{Sets \times Sets}$ or $\mathbf{Sets^2}$ are OK, then please use them.

Comment: You can take any product of two categories with a subobject classifier..

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg, could you elaborate? Let's consider the product Set x Set. Why isn't <1, 2> the subobject classifier?

Comment: No, do *not* consider an example, because it will make it harder for you to see the obvious. Consider $C \times D$ for any two categories $C,D$ which have subobject classifiers $\Omega_C$, $\Omega_D$. Please guess what the subobject classifier in the product will be. And then prove it. *Afterwards* you can specialize to examples.

Comment: Sometimes (and this is the case here, for sure) special examples obscure the relevant structure because there is lots of other structure present which is "in the way" to see clearly what is going on. Abstraction often helps to simplify things (given enough training in this line of thinking, of course). This is also precisely the reason why Qiaochu generalized from $\mathbf{Set}^2$ immediately to $\mathbf{Set}^n$. It does not help to look only at pairs of sets, better look at sequences of sets.

Answer (score 3):

$\text{Set}^2$ will work fine, but because of the multiple appearances of the number $2$ it will be less confusing to work with $\text{Set}^n$ for an arbitrary positive integer $n$ (we could more generally consider $\text{Set}^I$ for a possibly infinite index set $I$).

The subobject classifier is the object $2$ in the sense that it is the coproduct $1 \sqcup 1$; explicitly it is the object $(2, 2, 2, \dots)$. But there are $2^n$ morphisms $1 \to 2$, since we can pick a different one in each coordinate, so the subobject classifier is not "$2$-like" according to your definition.

In general, by the universal property of the subobject classifier, morphisms $1 \to \Omega$ are naturally in bijection with subobjects of $1$, that is, with equivalence classes of monomorphisms $m \hookrightarrow 1$. The subobjects of the terminal object are called [subterminal objects](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/subterminal+object), and it's not hard to see that in $\text{Set}^n$ the subterminal objects are the objects which are either $0$ (the empty set) or $1$ (a $1$-element set) in each coordinate; in particular there are (up to equivalence) $2^n$ of them, which matches the count above. This is another way to see that the subobject classifier can't be "$2$-like."

Comment: There are more complicated examples showing that the subobject classifier is usually not the coproduct $1 \sqcup 1$, e.g. sheaf topoi.

Comment: For one of the less complicated examples, you could also consider the category of directed graphs.  The final object has one vertex and one edge (a loop on the vertex).  This graph has 3 subobjects: the empty subobject, the full subobject, and then a subobject with the vertex but not with the edge.